# MDT 1709 - Newly Built Server - OSDComputerName is being overwritten

Tags: windows, deployment, mdt

Here's a weird one - I built an MDT server under the supervision of someone who really knows what they're doing. Stand alone network, no AD, no internet. DNS, DHCP, WDS, and MDT all on the same server.

Deployment of my Capture and SYSPREP'd image works fine. When all is said and done, the OSDComputerName does not push to the machine. Logs reflect no errors. Workstation shows a computer name of "WIN-XXXXXXXXX", there is nothing in the setup generating this name. The Wizard prompts for the computer name, and the unattended.xml shows the entered name without issue. My coworker suggested that I create a new unmodified TS, which I will try tomorrow (12/12). In the meantime, does anyone have a suggestion/insight?

Comment: We use a few different versions of a baseline WIM. So it is possible that the refered WIM is too baseline.

Testing another established WIM as the Capture and SYSPREP reference. Will report back findings.

Comment: No joy. The issue persists.

Comment: The problem, I've discovered is that I was unable to use the same name for both the sysprep and capture and final deploy machines. After the SYSPREP and Capture, I used the same name, and either a Windows update or something inherent in the MDT version does not like when you use the same name as the prepped and captured machine. So you have to give a junk/different name during your prep and capture if you plan to test the deployment. Or use a different name after the test deployment. 

Further research has shown that those using MDT for 1803 deployment have also experienced this.